# How to go to a specific character offset

Tags: bbedit

I'm on MacOS 10.15.7, using BBedit 13.5.5. Under "Go ->" There is only Go to Line Number. I want to go to character 145 of the file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a crib from page 103 of the user manual (you'll find it on the Help menu):

> Alternatively, you can jump to an absolute character offset, by using the ‘line:column’ syntax but leaving the ‘line’ blank or specifying it as zero. For example, entering “0:1500” or “:1500” will cause BBEdit to place the insertion point before the 1500th character in the document. (The range syntax works too; so you could use “0:12-0:56” to select characters 12 through 56.)

Answer (score 0):

Correct - if you select Go from the menu, it says, after selecting Line Number:

:C      character offset C in document

So, :20 goes to position 20.  But, I have found it is off a few characters, perhaps it is not counting line feed.